# What design pattern is used in this delegating scenario?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I am currently having to bend some framework API to fit my usecase.
The framework provides generic interfaces such as

```
public interface Processor<T> {
    T process(T t);
}
```

with various implementations. These are used by some classes such as

```
public SomeClass<T> {
    public SomeClass(Processor<T> p, [...]) {}
}
```

To fit my usecase, I need `SomeClass` to behave differently without affecting the existing `Processor`s.
To do so, `SomeClass` has to operate on wrapped `T`s. Hence:

```
SomeClass<Container<T>>
```

As said, this should not affect the `Processor`s which still shall operate on `T`. To be able to do this I wrote *delegators* which unwrap `T` from the container and then delegate the processing of `T`:

```
public class BoxDelegatingProcessor<T> implements Processor<Container<T>> {
    private Processor<T> delegatee;

    public Container<T> process(Container<T> wrapped) {
        return wrap(delegatee.process(unwrap(wrapped));
    }
    [...]
}
```

**What design pattern (according to GoF) is this?** 
I don't think it's Decorator, because there es no actual "functionality" involved? It's more of a type adapter.

Comment: This one sounds like decorator pattern

Comment: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology).

Comment: I don't know what GoF pattern this is.  But to me it looks like the purpose of the Processor interface is as follows: Process takes a T and returns a T, so it is possibly manipulating it in some way.  The purpose of passing a Processor interface to the SomeClass constructor is to be able to change the behavior of the processing WITHOUT NEEDING TO CHANGE SOMECLASS.  Instead, you would just create a new class that implements the process method.  I'm a little confused at what your BoxDelegatingProcessor is attempting to do.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need SomeClass<Container<T>>?  Could you not create a List or Array of SomeClass<T>  ??

Comment: The GOF patterns are not comprehensive.  There's no guarantee that any particular technique is covered by GOF.

Comment: Why is the name important? All patterns have to be customized to fit the scenario.

Comment: smells a lot like the [visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html). Further your intent sounds like the visitor pattern instead of the [decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html)

Comment: [The State Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern).  "Allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class."

Answer (score 1):

This is the adaptor pattern. You are adapting a `Processor<T>` so it can be used where a `Processor<Container<T>>` is expected.